# Permission denied NetApp export share

Tags: linux, nfs, file-sharing

We have NetApp NFS file server. I have shared /example filesystem on NFS and give two Linux host permission of `ROOT` level access. Interesting thing is ServerA can mount /example share and has full access on it read/write. But serverB has only Read-Only access. I gave both A/B full Root access then why only A has r/w but not B?

```
NetApp*> qtree status
Volume   Tree     Style Oplocks  Status
-------- -------- ----- -------- ---------
example unix  enabled  normal
```

Export details

```
NetApp> exportfs
/example      -sec=sys,rw,root=serverA:serverB
```

Mount share

```
[root@serverB /]# mount -o rw,hard,nointr,proto=tcp,nfsvers=3,bg,nolock netapp:/example /mnt
[root@serverB /]# cd /mnt/
[root@serverB mnt]# touch foo
touch: cannot touch `foo': Permission denied
```

NFS client debug logs

```
Jan  7 13:03:02 serverB kernel: NFS call  create foo
Jan  7 13:03:02 serverB kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:15/64 ct=1 info=0x7)
Jan  7 13:03:02 serverB kernel: NFS reply create: -13
Jan  7 13:03:02 serverB kernel: NFS: dentry_delete(/foo, 10)
Jan  7 13:03:02 serverB kernel: NFS: permission(0:15/64), mask=0x1, res=0
Jan  7 13:03:02 serverB kernel: NFS: lookup(/foo)
Jan  7 13:03:02 serverB kernel: NFS call  lookup foo
Jan  7 13:03:02 serverB kernel: NFS reply lookup: -2
Jan  7 13:03:02 serverB kernel: NFS: dentry_delete(/foo, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `anon=0` to the volume's options, e.g. via `/etc/exports`

For example:

```
rdfile /etc/exports
/vol/vol1    -sec=sys,rw,anon=0,nosuid
```

You can write the info using `wrfile` - just make sure you know how it works (overwrites the whole file, Ctrl+C to end)